# Formulario registro Flask Python

Tags: python, base-de-datos, flask

estoy un poco atascado en un ejercicio. Intento hacer un formulario tipico de login, pero algo no va bien. Tengo en una mii base de datos MySql un usuario con email root@gmail.com y contraseña 12345.
Mi base de datos se encuentra en localhost, raiz root y sigue con los datos que importo de la clase que he creado con ella.
Por ahora me devuelve la página tal cual, si pongo a adrede un email incorrecto no me da el mensaje que intento poner de "No eres usuario".

```
from flask import Flask

from flask import render_template

from flask import request

from paquete.conexion import Bd

app = Flask(__name__)
# rutas
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

if request.method == 'POST':
    try:  
        email = request.form('email')
        password = request.form('password')
        
        bd = Bd('localhost', 'root', 12345, 'login_registro')
        leer_email = bd.query(f'SELECT email FROM registro WHERE email = "{email}"')
        leer_password = bd.query(f'SELECT password FROM registro WHERE password = "{password}"')
        
        
    except IndexError:
        
        return render_template('index.html', mensaje="No eres usuario")

return render_template('index.html')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)`
```

Comment: Parece ser que no se está forzando el error tipo IndexError, y eso se debería forzar en el método query del objeto Bd o tras recibir en leer_email algo None o vacío (depende de cómo lo hayas programado), comparte el código del objeto Bd. Un saludo